# dd: invalid argument 'progress' to 'status'

Tags: dd, buildroot

In my [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html) Linux image I try do

```
dd if=/mnt/disk.img of=/dev/sda bs=4M conv=fsync status=progress
```

But I get error

```
dd: invalid argument 'progress' to 'status'
```

Why?

Comment: What Linux are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Buildroot's buildroot/.config set

```
BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX_SHOW_OTHERS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_COREUTILS=y
```

If still problem, check this options in your BusyBox's .config

```
CONFIG_DD
CONFIG_FEATURE_DD_THIRD_STATUS_LINE
```

To check you can watch file buildroot/output/build/busybox-1.35.0/.config (Please don't try to edit this file, it is auto-regenerated based on Buildroot's BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX_CONFIG option).

[image]